# 000webhost, PHP, and LoadVars AS2

Tags: php, actionscript-2, loadvars

I am using AS2 to download and upload data from an HTTP server using some PHP on the other end. The upload works great, but I ran into a little issue with the download, since the webhost that I am using appends a little HTML comment to the end of every file. My PHP works great, but this little HTML comment destroys the whole LoadVars variable string. For example:

```
&coins=211108&xp=751029&credits=5&blah=p
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img    src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>
 <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

I was wondering if anyone could think of a workaround since I personally have been trying to brainstorm and search for one for a while and couldn't. If worst comes to worst, I guess I can always either get a new webhost or host it myself.

Comment: This problem has been coming up a lot lately because 000webhost doesn't make it easy to find the link to turn off the analytics code.

Comment: I see. Hopefully this page will help some other people then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable analytics for 000webhost, read here:

http://www.000webhost.com/forum/announcements/2160-disabling-analytics-code.html

Comment: +1 This is the 3rd time I've seen similar problems with 000webhosting. I think they need to update their home page lest we have to update our FAQ. :)

Comment: thank you so much! I guess i should read more carefully b4 posting here :P and lol @herbert

Comment: I remember seeing the same question like 3 days ago too :S I don't understand why people skip what it'd be the first step to me, ask on their forums. Maybe afraid they may notice later that they're using some hacks to avoid it.

Comment: Agreed. That's where I checked when I first signed up some years ago. Still, they should make it an option in CPanel or something along those lines. @William, don't worry too much about it. A lot of free hosts _don't let you turn off analytics_ at all, so I guess people assume they **have** to use a hack.

Comment: I'm also having some trouble with loadvars. The send works perfectly but the load is being annoying. Is my string's syntax incorrect?

Comment: great post really usefull you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You could talk to them and ask them not to add it to such requests.

Or you could make your Actionscript ignore everything after a line break (but AFAIK, you'd have to write your own `LoadVars()` for that.

Other than that, I think you're out of luck!

Comment: yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @William you're welcome. (I edited in a paragraph with the only solution I can think of - in case you saw the first version of the answer.)

Comment: hmm.. that sounds easier said than done.. I guess I'll try it out.